# Pipe STDOUT & STDERR separately

Tags: linux, bash, alpine-linux

I have a function `test1` which produces output on both `stdout` and `stderr`:

```bsh
test1() {
    echo "out 1"
    sleep 0.1

    echo "error 1" 1>&2
    sleep 0.1

    echo "out 2"
    sleep 0.1

    echo "error 2" 1>&2
    sleep 0.1
}
```

I then have two aliases which *format* `stdin` and send it to `stdout`:

```bsh
alias o='sed -E "s/^/O /"'
alias e='sed -E "s/^/E /"'
```

How can I pipe the two streams from `test1` through `o` and `e` and end up with formatted output on `stdout` and `stderr`? I'm using Bash on Alpine Linux, so GNU utilities are not an option.

My reasoning goes as follows, but I don't know how to execute it syntactically:

1. Send `err` to `out` and `out` to `3`.
2. Run `in` through `e`, send to `err` and `3` to `out`.
3. Run `in` through `o`.
4. Profit?

Comment: `test1 > >(o) 2> >(e >&2)`?

Comment: @muru Sure but this leaves the process hanging and it's also out of order.

Comment: Once you send the streams to some other process, any chance of order goes out the window. (And it doesn't leave anything hanging for me, at least with the example you gave)

Comment: @muru Yeah, you are correct, it doesn't hang, just continues to produce output *after* I'm give back control over bash. Order is important for me though... I'm pretty sure pipes can do this nicely I just can't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using bash [process-subsitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

Note that you have to redirect it back to stderr in order to avoid it being picked up by the stdout pipe:

```
$ perl -E 'say {*STDOUT} "hi"; say {*STDERR} "bye"' \
        > >(sed s/^/out:/)                          \
       2> >(sed s/^/err:/ >&2)
```

Comment: It works. There is slight problem I can't figure out: put in script it gives `syntax error near unelected token \`>' ` and in second line `       > >(sed s/^/out:/) \' `. It persists if I put it in single line too.

Comment: @tansy Works for me. Are you using bash and not other type of shell? https://www.ideone.com/684tU0